# Widget - Android

Tags: android

подскажите способ ограничения количества экземпляров виджетов, например если больше двух, чтоб виджет сразу закрывался

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Widget - Android Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1020470/widget-android-studio)

Comment: нет это не дубликат, вопросы разные