# Widget - Android Studio

Tags: android

Подскажите как можно узнать название ресурса изображения ImageView, чтоб в условии проверить какое именно изображение в данный момент в ImageView.
Мне это нужно чтоб сделать картинку на виджете в качестве переключателя, если нажали на картинку, картинка в Imageview поменялась на другую, если снова нажали, то установилась прежняя.
по умолчанию при создании виджета записываю в ImageView таким способом

```
RemoteViews widgetView = new RemoteViews(ctx.getPackageName(), R.layout.test_widget);
widgetView.setImageViewResource(R.id.BT_WJTucha, R.drawable.image_1);

а далее нужно по клику на Image 
if (..?..) {
widgetView.setImageViewResource(R.id.BTimg_1, R.drawable.image_2);
}
else {
widgetView.setImageViewResource(R.id.BTimg_1, R.drawable.image_1);
}
```

буду признателен любой помощи

Comment: могу порекомендовать использовать статическую карту (Map) где ключом будет id виджета, а значением id ресурса

Comment: Спасибо Гигантское за ответ!
пожалуйста напишите пример кода реализации такого метода, если это не сложно, просто я новичок.
Спасибо!

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map